# Solve a system of M equations without specifying M

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra, summation

I am trying to write my game-theoretic model in *Wolfram Language*. There is only one remaining step and I am not sure if it is within reach of *Wolfram Language* (or *Mathematica*). I describe a simplified version of my problem below.

## Cournot game

There are $M$ firms. Each firm $i$ can produce some output $q_i\geq0$ at a cost of $c_i$ per unit. Once the firms have (simultaneously) decided on their outputs, the price is set in the market according to an inverse demand function $P(Q)=\alpha-Q$, where $Q=q_1+\ldots+q_M$ is the aggregate output and $\alpha>0$ is market size parameter. Firm $i$'s profits are $q_iP(Q)-q_ic_i=q_i(\alpha-q_1-\ldots-q_M-c_i)$. Each firm maximizes its profits taking outputs of the opponents as given. By differentiating the profit function with respect to $q_i$ and imposing the necessary condition for maximizing a function, I obtain the equilibrium outputs:
$$q_i^*=\frac{1}{2}\left(\alpha-\sum_{k\neq i}q_k^*-c_k\right) \text{ for } i=\{1,\ldots,M\}.$$
A quick derivation on the piece of paper gives me the explicit solution:
$$q_i^*=\frac{1}{M+1}\left(\alpha-Mc_i+\sum_{k\neq i}c_k\right)$$
**Here's the thing: I would like to obtain exactly this result (the above equation) in *Mathematica*. Is it possible?** Note: I don't want to substitute any numbers for $M, c_1, \ldots, c_M$ or $\alpha$. They are general, exogenous parameters.

In other words, the above problem boils down to inverting a $M\times M$ matrix of the form:
$$\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
2 & 1 & \ldots & 1\\
1 & 2 & \ldots & 1\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 & 1 & \ldots & 2
\end{array}\right].$$
Can one do this without specifying $M$?

Comment: If you have vectors c and q both of length m (any m) then Total[c q] does your calculation. You can create such vectors in many ways: ConstantArray[0,m] creates an m-length vector of zeros. RandomReal[{0,1},m] creates a vector of length m each of which is a random number in {0,1}.

Comment: No, that is not what I aim for. I have updated the description. I do not want to use specific values.

Comment: I feel the closest you could get to a vector of *symbolic* length would be [SymbolicTensors](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SymbolicTensors.html). However, they are mostly used in vector calculus like stuff (proving identities and so) and may not be what you are looking for. Perhaps it would help if you could elaborate a bit on what you want to do with them.

Comment: I extended the description, I hope that clarifies things a bit.

Comment: `IdentityMatrix[M] - 1/(M + 1) ConstantArray[1, M]`?

Comment: Honestly, I don't think you can do better than the Sherman-Morrison-Woodbury solution from bill. Why doesn't it suit your needs?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  the OP is asking for functionality that is not supported given the constraints the OP is putting on the solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can invert the matrix 
$$\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
2 & 1 & \ldots & 1\\
1 & 2 & \ldots & 1\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 & 1 & \ldots & 2
\end{array}\right].$$
(for general m) using the [Woodbury matrix identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity). First, let `one` be the m-vector of all ones. Then the matrix you want to invert is expressible as

```
mat = IdentityMatrix[m] + Outer[Times, one, one];
```

To use the matrix inversion lemma (with the notation from the wikipedia article), let A = IdentityMatrix[m], U=one, V=Transpose[one], C=A; and the lemma says the inverse is:

```
matInv= IdentityMatrix[m] - Outer[Times, one, one]/(m + 1);
```

This holds for all `m`. We can check this for an specific `m` like so:

```
m = 5;
one = ConstantArray[1, m];
eye = IdentityMatrix[m];
mat = eye + Outer[Times, one, one];
matInv = eye - Outer[Times, one, one]/(m + 1);
mat.matInv == matInv.mat == eye
```

to which the response is `True`. To do this truly within Mathematica, one approach would be to incorporate knowledge of the inversion lemma.

Comment: I'm afraid this does not solve the problem. Can one make this method work without specifying `m`?

Comment: If you want a numerical inverse to the matrix, then you must specify `m`. If you don't want a numerical inverse, then the formula for `matInv` is the answer: $I-1.1'/(m+1)$.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this:

```
cournotEq[m_] := (IdentityMatrix[m] - 
    1/(m + 1) ConstantArray[1, m]).Array[\[Alpha] - Subscript[c, #] &,  m]
cournotEq[2]//FullSimplify
```

$\left\{\frac{1}{3} \left(\alpha -2 c_1+c_2\right),\frac{1}{3} \left(\alpha +c_1-2
   c_2\right)\right\}$

```
cournotEq[3]//FullSimplify
```

$\left\{\frac{1}{4} \left(\alpha -3 c_1+c_2+c_3\right),\frac{1}{4} \left(\alpha +c_1-3
   c_2+c_3\right),\frac{1}{4} \left(\alpha +c_1+c_2-3 c_3\right)\right\} $

Comment: Almost. Can one make it work for `cournotEq[M]`? Without giving a concrete number? As it is, it is not possible. I want to get the exact equation I have given in the description (e.g. in a matrix form).

Comment: @KrzysztofBrzezinski, I don't think it is possible to have it work for symbolic `M`.